# Getting element properties in click handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

Forewarning: I'm a newbie to JQuery.

I have a collection of links and lists that look something like so. They're dynamically generated by my back end framework...

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a id="link1" class="special" href="#">...</a>
    <ul id="list1"> ... </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="link2" class="special" href="#">...</a>
    <ul id="list2"> ... </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a id="link3" class="special" href="#">...</a>
    <ul id="list3"> ... </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to learn JQuery and Unobtrustive Javascript, so I want to add a click handler on all the links with the class "special" that will toggle the related lists.

So...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a.special").click(function() {
     id = *magicFunctionToGetOwnID*
     $(convertListIDtoLinkID(id)).toggle
  })
})
```

What is the magic function that I need? What about if I want to get other properties of the thing I'm attaching a handler to? Say, in the future, I add a "toggle-target" property and I would want to get that?

Comment: My question wasn't worded very well. The answers below explain what I was trying to accomplish quite well. :) What I was trying to learn I figured out thanks to their direction. To get the ID it would be `$(this).attr('id')` and if I later added a toggle-target attribute, it would be `$(this).attr('toggle-target')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure If I get you right, but it looks like you want something like this:

```
$(function() {
   $('ul:first').delegate('a.special', function( event ) {
       $(this).next('ul').toggle();
   });
});
```

You don't should bind an event handler to all nodes in a situation like that. It's enough to bind one handler to a shared parent and make use of the event bubbling.

**Update**
`.delegate()` does exactly what I described above. It'll bind the *event handler* to a node. The trick is, that event if that event is triggered on a *child node* from the *delegated* node, the events will "reach" our destination by bubbling up the DOM tree (unless explicitly prohibit event bubbling). However, jQuery is nice and will always bind `this` to the target node (the node which originally received the event).

Have a read: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: What is the difference between $('a.special').click(function() { ... }) and $('ul:first').delegate('a.special', function( event) { ... })? I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Ah. I understand now. Could you also explain why this would be advantageous rather than just using $('a.special')? Much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `$(this).parent().find("ul").toggle()`. It is rather self-explanatory.

http://jsfiddle.net/gLu9a/

Answer (score 1):

The way to get an element's own id is with the `id` property.  The element that was clicked is set as `this` within the handler, so you can use `this.id`.

That said, this is not an optimal technique.  Use DOM relationships, rather than setting ids, wherever you can.  This will make your code more flexible and intuitive.  In this case, you can use the [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) method, to get the DOM element that follows the element that was clicked:

```
$(this).next().toggle();
```

See the [API "traversing" category](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) for more ways of adjusting a selection.